# Are there any way to hide the dock icon but keep the menubar icon?

Tags: mac, dock

Edit .plist will hide both menubar and dock icon. Are there any way to hide the dock icon but keep the menubar icon?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly are you trying to achieve, and what you've tried so far?

Comment: What ".plist"? What to you mean by "_hide the dock icon but keep the menubar icon_"? Do you mean _the_ **Dock** and _the_ **Menu Bar**? If not, what icon are you referring to? What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: what is a "menubar icon"  there are toolbars, and a menu bar with menus.

Answer (score 3):

You have to edit the Plist file for the app. Plist files use a key/value format, declaring the type of the key. The correct code is:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>true</string>
```

Stick these in before the `</dict> </plist>` lines, and *voilà*. This works as late as High Sierra, and on the apps I have done this for it does eliminate the dock icon but not the menu bar one.

Comment: This does not work as of Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try this app http://foggynoggin.com/dockdodger

Works well for me

Comment: Doen't it mess up Gatekeeper protection and updates via App Store?